# Trying to hide all other elements with class name using .not(this)

Tags: jquery

Trying to hide all others, but it keeps affecting the $(this) item.

```
$(function() {
$(".FL-pest-indv").css({ display: 'none' });
$(".FL-pest-cat").live('click',
function() {
    $(".FL-pest-indv").not($(this)).hide(600);
    $(this).children('.FL-pest-indv').stop(true, true).animate({ "height": "toggle" ,   "opacity" : "toggle"},600);
        }); 
        });
```

nor

```
$(function() {
$(".FL-pest-indv").css({ display: 'none' });
$(".FL-pest-cat").live('click',
function() {
    $(".FL-pest-indv").not(this).hide(600);
    $(this).children('.FL-pest-indv').stop(true, true).animate({ "height": "toggle" ,   "opacity" : "toggle"},600);
        }); 
        });
```

are working for me.

Comment: Can you reproduce this at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It looks like it *should* be working.

Comment: html output was too large, here's a jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eteich/nLukd/3/

it's mostly working, but when you click on the the open parent, it just reopens it instead of closing it.

Comment: I don't see the issue with the code. It seems to be working

Comment: If you extend one then click on the exteneded one again, it does not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the answer in my function all along.

```
$(function() {
$(".FL-pest-indv").css({ display: 'none' });
$(".FL-pest-cat").live('click',
function() {
    $(".FL-pest-indv").not($(this).children('.FL-pest-indv')).hide(600);
    $(this).children('.FL-pest-indv').stop(true, true).animate({ "height": "toggle" ,   "opacity" : "toggle"},600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).siblings().hide(600)`

Comment: This just starts hiding everything else that is .FL-pest-cat

Comment: I want it to hide all other instances of .FL-pest-indv

Answer (score -1):

Try .not("#" + $(this).attr('id'))

Comment: $(this) does not act as a string.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't - but $(this).attr('id') most certainly is (so I don't see why this warrants a downvote, but whatever).

Comment: He also is using classes so it would have to be `.not("." + $(this).attr('class'))` to work. So yes, a downvote.

Comment: Even set to affect classes, this doesn't work either. The original code works except if you click on the currently open class' parent, then it just reopens it.

Comment: Well, classes don't make sense for this problem.  Also - are you really not using IDs here?  If so, then Jonah is correct that my original suggestion won't work for that reason.  I assumed IDs were being used.

Comment: I'm not using ID's, because this content is being generated dynamically and I don't want 12 identical id's on the page.